# Update existing node (not created by Migrate) via Migrate 8.5.x

Tags: migrations

I have got existing Drpal 8.5 site with hundreds of nodes. With migrate, if i try to upgrade, new nodes are rather created. Node have a field which is being used as key however that seem to be not working. It seems that node are only updated if their record present in migrate_map_xyz. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Updating existing content was possible by changing the default behaviour of a migration with the [system of record concept](https://www.drupal.org/node/1117454) in **Drupal 7**.

In **Drupal 8** this concept has been [revised](https://www.drupal.org/node/2808425) & is available with the `overwrite_properties` option in the destination of the migration YAML:

```
...
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  # define the entity properties that are to be updated.
  overwrite_properties:
    - title
    - field_foo
    - field_bar
...
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it work. Here is the code; with this, it still creates new nodes.
`Source:
  plugin: csv
  path: public://migrate/simple_assets.csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - serial
  column_names:
    0:
      serial: 'Serial/Service Tag'
    1:
      type: 'Type'
(source plugin data here)
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  override_properties:
    - serial
    - type`
`serial,type
ABC123,Laptop
XYZ124,Laptop`

Comment: [Migration YAML](https://codeshare.io/5PPppd) and [CSV](https://codeshare.io/2EWMMo)